# Getting the exact result value

Tags: trigonometry

How can I get the exact number of this equation?
[image: Equation]
The exact value is 0.04924.

Comment: `cos` should be `Cos`. In *Mathematica*, all built in functions and symbols begin with capital letters.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all built-in math functions in mathematica are capitalized. Just capitalize "cos" and it should work:

```
(5.1 - 5)/2 * Cos[10 Pi/180]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to find the answer on the internet, but I didn't realize the mistake. Finally this works.